# RxJava2 Android onNext is called even after disposing compositeDisposable onDestroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, observable, rx-java2, android-mvp

Following is my code for adding observable to composite disposable

```
compositeDisposable.add(retrofit.create(APIService.class).getHomePageItems(homePageRequestParam.buildPost(), homePageRequestParam.build())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onTerminateDetach()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<HomePageResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(HomePageResult result) {
                    appView.onHomePageResponse(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    appView.onHomePageError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            }));
```

On Fragment destroy I am calling presenter stop() method as below.

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    appPresnter.setView(null);
     appPresnter.onStop();
}
```

Clearing and disposing observable inside presenter as below

```
 @Override
public void onStop() {
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
    compositeDisposable.clear();


}
```

But still onNext is called even though fragment is not available and I am getting null pointer exception.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Why it is happening?

Comment: try shifting `appPresnter.setView(null);
     appPresnter.onStop();` above super line in `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `view` to `null` before clearing the `CompositeDisposable` allowing for an `onNext()` call before disposal:

This :

```
appPresnter.setView(null);
appPresnter.onStop();
```

Should be transposed to :

```
appPresnter.onStop();
appPresnter.setView(null);
```

Also probably makes sense to do your clear up in `Fragment::onDestroyView` or `Fragment::onStop` rather than `Fragment::onDestroy`